# Cribbage Scoring Difficulties

Tags: cribbage

We ran into a friendly argument while playing cribbage today and we're stumped as to how to count this hand.  How do you count 3 Sixes, 1 Seven and 1 Eight?

Answer (score 8):

First of all, there's only one fifteen: the seven and the eight.  That's two points.  (Note that the sixes can't participate in 15s at all)

Next, there are three runs of three: each six in turn, the seven, and the eight.  That's 3*3 = nine points.

Finally, there's the trio of sixes, worth six points (or equivalently, three pairs of sixes).

So the final score for the hand is 2+9+6 = 17 points.

Comment: Another way to look at the hand is taking the shortcut that you have a triple run which is worth 15 (as opposed to a double double run which is 16) with a single "fifteen-two" for a total of 17 points.

Comment: @corsiKa: Those shortcuts are important in becoming a better player.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a web page that you can use to score any cribbage hand:

http://www.bucktheodds.com/cribbage/score

And, here is your specific hand

http://www.bucktheodds.com/cribbage/score?cardsText=6S,6D,6H,7S,8D

The page is really cool because it shows a list of all scoring combinations:

```
Scoring Details
15 Count    7S,8D       2
Pairs       6H,6S,6D    6
Straights   6S,7S,8D    9
            6D,7S,8D    
            6H,7S,8D    
Jack                    0
Flush                   0
Total                   17
```